# Could I plot data from other papers in my figures for comparison?

Tags: ethics

It's necessary for my current paper to compare some values from my work and previous work. Since the mean and std values of previous work are shown in their paper, could I plot some bar chart for the comparison between mine and theirs(of course I'll specify the source of the data)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Note that data *per se* isn't copyrightable in most places. But citation is proper to avoid any charge of plagiarism.

Comment: Very much thanks!

Comment: In particular there is no problem or step to be taken if you replot the data togheter with your data in a new figure, except for a clear citation in caption and in the references list. Otherwise a side by side comparison will require permission.